# Check for administrator privileges in C#

Tags: c#, .net, privileges, administrator, rights

I want to know if a program is running as administrator.

The user doesn't have to be administrator. I only want to know if my application has rights to edit some secured files that are editable when running as Administrator.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I tell if my process is running As Administrator?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/509292/how-can-i-tell-if-my-process-is-running-as-administrator)

Comment: I just Googled that question and it looks like I asked it 3 years ago. Good to know. Thanks Google.

Answer (score 122, accepted):

This will return a bool valid

```
using System.Security.Principal;

bool isElevated;
using (WindowsIdentity identity = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent())
{
    WindowsPrincipal principal = new WindowsPrincipal(identity);
    isElevated = principal.IsInRole(WindowsBuiltInRole.Administrator);
}
```

Comment: +1 because that even works on Linux (Mono). Gives you true when ran as root/via sudo. Gives false as a default user.

Comment: If you build for .NET 5.0, you get: error CA1416: This call site is reachable on all platforms. 'WindowsBuiltInRole.Administrator' is only supported on: 'windows'.

Answer (score 13):

Here's @atrljoe's answer turned into a one liner using the latest C#:

```
using System.Security.Principal;

static bool IsElevated => new WindowsPrincipal(WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent()).IsInRole(WindowsBuiltInRole.Administrator);
```

Comment: This is ugly. I'm sorry. But really, you should shorten everythiing. It is bette to leave it as 4 lines and make function out of it.

How to even debug your one liner?

Comment: I believe that terseness is a vitue, as long as it's clear.

Comment: Interesting... I find this easier to read than the expanded version. This has a clear call hierarchy, whereas to understand code exploded into different variables, I need to mentally execute it.

Comment: Another downside of this form is that [you never call `Dispose` as you are required by contract to do](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20100809-00/?p=13203)

Comment: My downvote is because it isn't disposed of, as Ian said.

Comment: Not only is it ugly, it's not clear what it does.  I'm in the "clear and concise even if it takes more lines of code" boat.

Comment: This exact code would be ten times more readable if it were just made multi-line. Comments won't allow formatting, but if you insert a carriage return directly after the => operator, and after the Windows Principle constructor call, readability would be vastly better. Irrelevant, though, because you really do have to dispose that WindowsIdentity.

Answer (score 2):

To avoid `SecurityException`, and leaks, like not closing `WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent()`, since `WindowsPrincipal` does not explicitly close, but only creates a new connection and only then closes it.

```
private static bool IsAdministrationRules() {
   try {
       using (WindowsIdentity identity = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent()) {
          return (new WindowsPrincipal(identity)).IsInRole(WindowsBuiltInRole.Administrator);
       }
   } catch {
       return false;
   }
}
```