# Detect if application is running under system account?

Tags: c#, .net, account

I could probably use `Environment.UserName` and compare that to 'system' to see if it matches, but that seems hacky and I'm not sure how it would work in a non English environment. Any other suggestions on how to check if the current executable is running as the system account?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/509292/how-can-i-tell-if-my-process-is-running-as-administrator

Comment: @Snoopy, those (and even all the links those point to) refer to checking if "running as administrator".

Further reading, they are VERY close though.

Comment: You working with C# or C++ because `[Environment]::UserName` isn't valid C#.  Why do you feel it feels hacky, I see nothing wrong with it, if it does what you want it to do.

Comment: @Ramhound he told you the app **will not run correctly** on non-english language packs.

Comment: You can do the same thing for the `SYSTEM` account - which should have SID `S-1-5-18`: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/243330

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This should do it:

```
bool isSystem;
using (var identity = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent())
{
    isSystem = identity.IsSystem;
}
```

Never compare the account names. Comparing the user name to "System" would indeed fail on a localized OS.