# Is there a way to check the execution level of your program?

Tags: visual-studio, security, manifest

I am currently working on a Windows Forms application that, for some functionality, needs admin privileges to modify an *.ini* file for a legacy application that is referenced. However, it is known that no all users will have admin rights.

My current idea is to add an `app.manifest` file to the solution and set the `requestedExecutionLevel` to `highestAvailable` in order to request admin rights if possible and otherwise run at the default security. `app.manifest` settings for reference:

```
<requestedPrivileges xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
  <!-- UAC Manifest Options
       If you want to change the Windows User Account Control level replace the 
       requestedExecutionLevel node with one of the following.

  <requestedExecutionLevel  level="asInvoker" uiAccess="false" />
  <requestedExecutionLevel  level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
  <requestedExecutionLevel  level="highestAvailable" uiAccess="false" />

      Specifying requestedExecutionLevel element will disable file and registry virtualization. 
      Remove this element if your application requires this virtualization for backwards
      compatibility.
  -->
  <requestedExecutionLevel level="highestAvailable" uiAccess="false" />
</requestedPrivileges>
```

My question is, is it then possible to detect the execution level so I can then modify the app's behavior based on if the user has admin access?

**Edit:** I am looking for a way to check specifically if the the app itself is run at an elevated level as opposed to at a default security if possible. The suggested solution of validating the user's permissions level is a potential/partial solution, but I would much prefer, if possible, to verify the behavior of the app directly as opposed to potential level of the user.

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509292/how-can-i-tell-if-my-process-is-running-as-administrator help you?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I tell if my process is running as Administrator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509292/how-can-i-tell-if-my-process-is-running-as-administrator)

Comment: Note that "highestAvailable" will not grant you elevated rights, even if the user _is_ admin.

Comment: @PMF The looks along the right route. That question's answer appears to detect if the user is a valid admin which is a potential solution, but the comments on the question raise concerns that detecting the user's rights does not inherently give the status of the app. That could be a solution if necessary, but I would prefer a method to directly detect if the app itself is run at that level if possible.

Comment: I think answer 3 on that page is what you're looking for.

Comment: @PMF What sorting type do you use when talking about "answer 3"? Better name the answer's author or provide a direct link to the answer.

Comment: @Robert Sorry. I mean the answer from Brian Legend.

Comment: @PMF Oh I see. That looks like what I am looking for. I will do testing with this code. Thank you.